# Create an array/list and and use a for loop to print in informix

Tags: informix

Create an integer or float array and print the elements using for loop
in a procedure/function in Informix

I have referred to the info centre and almost googled but couldn't be able to find it out:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE main()
     begin
     #SET @myArrayOfValue := '2,5,2,23,6,';
     #print the elements
    end;
end procedure
```

- define an array of elements either in procedure or function.
- perform some looping and print.

Comment: 'Tis an odd request; Informix doesn't have support for arrays per se, AFAICR.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Thanks for the response.i could see Informix supporting lists as below

Comment: DEFINE  var LIST(INTEGER NOT NULL);

Comment: Can u suggest I want to assign some values to above list

Comment: Yes, but a list is not an array.  It is a list.  It is very dangerous (or silly if you prefer a less dramatic description) to use one term with precise meaning for another term with precise (but different) meaning.  Computer programming requires precision.

Comment: How to assign values to a list